How to fix "x509: cannot validate certificate" error in WSO2 APIM apictl
I created an Env "dev" and connected it to the running WSO2 APIM instance using this command:
apictl env dev --apim https://<ip address>:9443

When I login to the envinronment I'm getting this error:

Error in connecting Reason: Post "https:///client-registration/v0.17/register": tls: failed to verify certificate: x509: cannot validate certificate for  because it doens't contain any IP SANs

I just add the pem of the WSO2 APIM in the ../.wso2apictl/certs
I'm not sure if that's is the correct way.

Please [edit] your question title to describe the problem you're having or question you're asking. Your title now is the useless Need help, which we know already because you're asking here, followed by the inappropriate repetition of tag information. Your title should be clear and descriptive enough that a future site user who is skimming a list of search results will know what it's about, and your title now says nothing meaningful. For suggestions on writing a good title, see [ask].

Yes, you can add the certificate to the certs directory found in APICTL_CONFIG_DIR/.wso2apictl. (The default location of the certs directory is /home/.wso2apictl/certs)
The certificates added to this directory will be imported whenever an action is performed with apictl. Any DER or PEM encoded certificate with the file extensions of *.pem, *.crt or *.cer can be used with apictl.
Also, if you want to skip SSL validation you can use the -k flag when executing the apictl.

Okay thank you it worked, I didn't notice the -k command in the -help. I have successfully migrated an API and APP.
